# Mit vierzig oder in meine Vierziger

Tags: numbers

Ich will sagen:

> learning a new language in my forties

Soll ich so sagen?

> Mit vierzig eine neue Sprache lernen

Oder so?

> In meinen Vierzigern eine neue Sprache lernen

Answer (score 2):

Deine beiden Ansätze haben unterschiedliche Bedeutungen. "Mit vierzig" bezieht sich auf Dein vierzigstes Lebensjahr, eben wenn Du vierzig Jahre alt bist. Ab Deinem einundvierzigsten Geburtstag würde es dann "mit einundvierzig" heißen.

"In meinen Vierzigern" (nicht "in meine Vierziger") bezieht sich auf das gesamte Jahrzehnt, also von Deinem vierzigsten bis zu Deinem neunundvierzigsten Lebensjahr. An Deinem fünfzigsten Geburtstag beginnen also "meine Fünfziger".

Wenn Du "in my forties" übersetzen willst, ist "in meinen Vierzigern" sogar eine ziemlich wörtliche Übersetzung.